# Refer to "parent" form from the dialog form

Tags: ms-access, modal-dialog

I have a form with a button that opens another form in dialog mode. Is there a dialog form property that contains information about the form which opened it? Something like Me.Parrent in sobform? The only way I know to achieve that is to use OpenArgs, but hoping for something more strict...

Thanks for any suggestions

Smok.

Comment: _OpenArgs_ is pretty flexible. You can pass either the form name or the form index of the Forms collection.

Comment: No property. Options are OpenArgs, global variable, TempVars, set value of textbox on the dialog form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not opening multiple variants of the same form, the `Forms` collection is the usual way to do it, like Gustav said.

You can access the form object like this:

`Forms!ParentformName.Form`

There are loads of other ways to refer to variables, June7 noted the most common ones. I prefer a global variable in the subform object

On the subfrom:

```vb
Public Parentform As Form
```

On the main form:

```vb
Private Sub OpenForm
    DoCmd.OpenForm "myForm"
    Forms!myForm.Parentform = Me.Form
End Sub
```

Or, to open a dialog form that's dependent on the main form:

```vb
Private dialogForm As Form
Private Sub OpenForm
    Set dialogForm = New Form_myForm
    dialogForm.Parentform = Me.Form
    dialogForm.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Note that the last approach has several advantages, such as supporting multiple instances of the dialog form, and being able to do multiple things from the subform (especially if you change the `Private dialogForm As Form` to `Private WithEvents dialogForm As Form` which allows you to detect when the dialog box closes, get values entered in the dialog box, handle them on the main form, and more. It does require that the dialogForm has a form module.)

Comment: Thank You for wide explanation of the subject. One more question, is it possible to open form as dialog using the last approach (with the "new" keyword)?

Comment: @Smok not as far as I know, but you can just set the `PopUp` property to `True` to make it always open like that. It can't be changed when opening, though, since it's read only unless the form is in design view.